# upgrading to android 10 on RedMi Note 5

Tags: applications, miui, redmi

I have made system update on my Redmi Note 5. Before system update it has Android version 7.2. Now after I do system update it is showing MIUI version 11.0.5.0 and Android Version 9PKQ1.180904.001. I do not understand what is this android version indicates, is it android version 7 or 8 or 9 or 10? I did not understand. Now I want to update my android version on RedMi Note 5 to Android 10, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's Android 9](https://adimorahblog.com/new-global-stable-update-for-the-redmi-note-5/)

> The Redmi Note 5 was launched back in 2017, running Snapdragon 625 with MIUI 9.5 based Android 8.1 Oreo. It has since picked the Android 9 Pie. However, in the last couple of months, the device has not received any form of support, and amid the arrival of MIUI 12 update on the device, Xiaomi has now released a new global stable update for the Redmi Note 5.

> The update is based on MIUI 11. It brings the August security patch to the device in a 523MB size package, and with a version number, **MIUI 11.0.5.0 PEIMIXM**

It was launched with Oreo according to this blog, not Android 7

From what I read, your device does not have stock upgrade to Android 10. You can look for custom ROMs on XDA.